# Help to understand a proof in topology (quotient spaces)

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the proof of the following proposition from "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" from John M. Lee.

> $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Suppose $q: X \to Y$ is an open quotient map. Then $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if the set $R=\{(x_1,x_2):q(x_1)=q(x_2)\}$ is closed in $X \times X$.

I have a question about the proof of the second implication :

> Assume $R$ is closed. Given distinct points $y_1, y_2 \in Y$, choose $x_1, x_2 \in X$ such that $q(x_i)=y_i$. Because $(x_1,x_2) \notin R$, **there is a product neighborhood $U_1 \times U_2$ of $(x_1,x_2)$** that is disjoint from $R$. Since $q$ is open, $q(U_1)$ and $q(U_2)$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $y_1$ and $y_2$, respectively.

I understood the logic of the proof but not the part in bold. I know that since $R$ is closed, $(X \times X) \setminus R$ is open and therefore for every point in $(X \times X) \setminus R$, in particular ($x_1,x_2)$, there is a neighborhood contained in $(X \times X) \setminus R$ so disjointed from $R$. But I do not understand why we can choose this neighborhood to be a product neighborhood?

Comment: How do you define a neighbourhood of $(x,x)$ in the product $X\times X$?

Comment: @Zest the product topology of $X \times X$ is the topology generated by the basis $B = \{U_1 \times U_2 : U_i \text{ are open in } X \}$. From this, a neighborhood of $(x,x)$ is just an open subset of $X \times X$ that contains $(x,x)$, which can be written as a union of  elements of $B$.

Comment: @Zest I think that I may know why, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $(x_1,x_2)$ disjoint from $R$, then $U$ can be written as a union of products of open subset in $X$, since $(x_1, x_2)$ is in the union, there must be a least one product that contains it, this product is then a candidate for a product neighborhood that I am looking for. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The claim in question:

> Let $q: X \mapsto Y$ be an open quotient map. If the set $R = \{ x_1 \times x_2 \in X \times X : q (x_1) = q (x_2) \}$ is closed, then $Y$ is Hausdorff.

We can prove it as follows.

Let $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ be distinct. Since $q$ is a quotient map, it is surjective, so there exist $x_1, x_2 \in X$ such that $q (x_1) = y_1 \ne q (x_2) = y_2$. Clearly then, $x_1 \times x_2 \notin R$. This much should be clear.

Since $R$ is closed, its complement $X \times X - R$ is open. Since $x_1 \times x_2$ is an element of $X \times X - R$, there must exist a basis element of the product topology on $X \times X$, denote it by $U_1 \times U_2$, satisfying $x_1 \times x_2 \in U_1 \times U_2 \subseteq X \times X - R$. By definition, the set $\mathcal{B} = \{ V \times W : V, W \in \mathcal{T}_X \}$, where $\mathcal{T}_X$ is the topology on $X$, forms a basis for the product topology on $X \times X$.

Since $U_1 \times U_2$ is a basis element of the product topology on $X \times X$, then $U_1$ and $U_2$ are each open in $X$. But $q$ is open, so the images $q (U_1)$ and $q (U_2)$ are each open in $Y$; they also satisfy $y_1 \in q (U_1)$ and $y_2 \in q (U_2)$. Finally, it is straightforward to show that $q (U_1)$ and $q (U_2)$ are disjoint. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists $y \in q (U_1) \cap q (U_2)$. Then there exists $z_1 \in U_1$ with $q (z_1) = y$, and $z_2 \in U_2$ with $q (z_2) = y$. Since $q (z_1) = q (z_2)$, then $z_1 \times z_2 \in R$ by definition. But $z_1 \times z_2 \in U_1 \times U_2 \subseteq X \times X - R$, a contradiction. Thus, $q (U_1)$ and $q (U_2)$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $y_1$ and $y_2$, respectively.

Since $y_1, y_2$ were arbitrary, $Y$ is Hausdorff, as desired.